# jekyll page.url doesn't work as it should be

Tags: jekyll

Lets say it's the code snippet:

```
<ul>
{% assign navigation = site.data.nav %}
{% for link in navigation %}
    {% assign active = nil %}
    {% for sublink in link.submenu %}
        {% if page.url contains sublink.url %}
            {% assign active = 'active' %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page.url contains link.url %}
        {% assign active = 'active' %}
    {% endif %}
    <li class="{{ active }}>
        <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ link.url }}">{{ link.text }}</a>
        {% if link.submenu %}
        <ul>
            {% for sublink in link.submenu %}
            <li {% if page.url contains sublink.url %}class="active"{% endif %}>
                <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ sublink.url }}">{{ sublink.text }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The nav.yml file looks like this:

```
- text: First Menu
  url: /modules/some text/introduction/

- text: Second Menu
  url: /modules/some more text/intro-text/
  submenu:
  - text: Level Two First
    url: /modules/level two first/intro-text/
  - text: Level Two Second
    url: /modules/level two second/intro-text/
```

So, every menu item renders and also works fine as it should be. But the only issue i'm getting here is the variable active isn't getting updated according to those if rather staying nil. Also the following line isn't getting that active class rendered even if the page.url contains sublink.url or link.url

```
<li {% if page.url contains sublink.url %}class="active"{% endif %}>
```

What might be the issue??

Comment: Is it because those link.url or sublink.url are actually modules' url?? so, how to really compare whether the current loaded page url contains that sublink.url or link.url?? Any idea?? I have tried site.url instead of page.url but didn't get any result

Comment: i got this solved breaking the url in the nav,yml in three parts and comparing the module name with page.categories :)